# Space and new line after every n'th character

Tags: python

I've got a string that gets imported from a text file, with the following

```
code: input_file.open("text_file.txt", 'r')
text = input_file.read()
input_file.close()
```

Now my problem is that the string is going to be between 1-999 long. I need to somehow have a space after every 10th letter, and a new line every 60th letter.

At the moment I've tried using:

```
def insertNewLines(text, lineLength):
  if len(text) <= lineLength:
     return text
  else:
     return text[:60] + ' '.join(text[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(text),10)) + insertNewLines(text[60:],60)
```

What I want to do is import a sequence of letters (1-999) from a text file, then use python to import the sequence into an HTML file, which then writes an HTML file with the imported sequence colorcoded/numbered/splitup and in a viewable format.
I've already got the HTML file working, but I can't get the text to have a space after 10 letters and a new line after every 60th.

This is what my current attempt looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0LdZ.jpg).

Comment: ...and what's wrong with what you're trying?

Comment: What I'm trying gives a line without spaces/newlines, then after 60letters, does it properly. If it makes any difference, between each new line, there's supposed to be numbering of the letters eg. 1 -10spaces- 10 - 10spaces - 20 etc. up to 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `join` and stepping through every `nth` character using `range`. Once your text is split up the way you want it, you can then split it on the `\n` and then insert the `p` elements in between each line.

```
f = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' * 35 #this generates a 910 character string

def break_apart(sep, step):
    return sep.join(f[n:n + step] for n in range(0, len(f), step))


f = break_apart(' ', 10)
f = break_apart('\n', 60)    

p = '<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60</p>'
fp = '\n'.join(j for i in f.split('\n') for j in [p, i])

html = '<div>{}</div>'.format(fp)

print(html)

<div>
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLMN OPQRSTUVWX YZABC
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
DEFGH IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
 GHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGH
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
IJKLMN OPQRSTUVWX YZABCDEFGH IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJK
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
L MNOPQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF GHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJ KLM
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
NOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLMN OPQRSTUVWX YZABCDEFGH IJKLMNOP
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
QR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF GHIJKLMNOP QR
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
STUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLMN OPQRSTU
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
VWX YZABCDEFGH IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUV W
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
XYZABCDEF GHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZ
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
ABCD EFGHIJKLMN OPQRSTUVWX YZABCDEFGH IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB 
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
CDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF GHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ ABCDE
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
FGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLMN OPQRSTUVWX YZABCDEFGH
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
 IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJKL MNOPQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF GHIJ
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
KLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZABCD EFGHIJKLM
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
N OPQRSTUVWX YZABCDEFGH IJKLMNOPQR STUVWXYZAB CDEFGHIJKL MNO
<p>1 10 20 30 40 50 60<p>
PQRSTUV WXYZABCDEF GHIJKLMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I want it to do, it doesn't seem to work though. If it makes any difference, my input is imported from a txt.file in 1 long sequence. It's then supposed to be copied into HTML so I can make it look "nice". 
Would it be helpful if I post all the code I'm currently using?

Comment: @JacobSørensen Copying this to HTML *does* make a difference; it changes the expected behavior of what your original question is asking.

Comment: How can I show the rest of my code? A basic explanation would be that I'm importing a sequence of letters (1-999) from a text file, then using python to import the sequence into an HTML file, which then writes an HTML with the imported sequence colorcoded/numbered/splitup and in a viewable format. Thanks

Comment: @JacobSørensen I edited my answer that should point you in the right direction

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Couple of questions, using your code, where would I insert the rest of my formatting?
I've been using output_file.write() to write my formatting and then output_file.write(f) to insert the imported sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your 'text_file' has Newlines in it, read line by line.

```
  text = []
  # My Sample Text files are utf-8 encoded
  with io.open( 'text_file.txt','r', encoding='utf8') as fh:
    for row,line in enumerate(fh,1):
      text.append(line)
    #end for
  #end with = closing fh
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: Hi, my text file should not have any spaces or new lines, it should be 1 long sequence of letters.

Comment: Did you mean a HTML Line Break instead of simple \n?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure 100% sure, I need the line breaks to be done to an imported string, but the string is to be imported into an HTML file for formatting.

Comment: A \n does not have any formating effect on Display HTML. You habe to replace any \n with <br>. In the sample from Wondercricket replace: f = break_apart('<br>', 60)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a consistent string of text as input:

```
import string
import random


text = ''
for i in range(16):
    text += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)*10

def insert_new_lines(input_string):
    output = []
    for i in range(0, len(text), 60):
        output.append(' '.join([text[j:j+10] for j in range(i, i+60, 10)]))
    return '\n'.join(output)


print insert_new_lines(text)
```

returns, using random letters as an example:

```
ssssssssss mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm wwwwwwwwww zzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaa
llllllllll llllllllll ffffffffff rrrrrrrrrr cccccccccc nnnnnnnnnn
rrrrrrrrrr xxxxxxxxxx uuuuuuuuuu qqqqqqqqqq
```